# How to prevent node benchmark package from optimizing (or allowing to be optimized) the functions it's benchmarking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, benchmarking

I was THRILLED when a few changes I made to a function resulted in it running over 1 BILLION TIMES PER SECOND (it was running around 5 million times per second previously to that change... a 200x increase!).

The slight change was returning an object which is initialized in the return statement, as opposed to creating the object, changing one of it's values, and then returning that object... not really a 200x optimization-worthy refactoring.

I was pretty pleased with myself until I tried benchmarking a completely empty function and low and behold ... it ran the ~same amount of times as the expensive function I was trying to benchmark... about 1.3 billion times per second.

What am I doing wrong?

Javascript is obviously optimizing something behind the scenes but I can't figure out what.

When I add in a bit of code to randomize the return values of the functions, it ruins the benchmark... because it's running extra code in the function that would not normally be there.

Comment: The JS optimizer has all sorts of tricks up its sleeve and very minor changes can make you fall out of an optimization path or help you get into one.  If you ask me, it's sort of worth it to read a few of the general do's and don'ts related to optimized code, but it's a moving target (can easily change from one JS release to the next and is certainly different in different JS engines) so there's no point in trying to spend a lot of effort on it.  Nothing specific anyone here can offer without seeing your EXACT code.

Comment: Agree with @jfriend00 100%, but what I will add most languages these days the same could be said, C#, Rust, Go etc, all have some very clever compiler tricks, and what might look like totally optimised code might run slower than code you didn't even bother trying to optimise.  Generally speaking I would say you never really want to try and optimise code per se, but optimise the approach you take at a higher level.

Comment: https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html